# MySQL Cluster issue with table updates

Tags: mysql, replication, cluster-computing

I have two MySQL clusters setup for replication.  My setup is as follows:

CLUSTER A
db001 - Management / SQL Node (Replication Master)
db002 - Management / SQL Node
db003 - Storage Node
db004 - Storage Node

CLUSTER B
db005 - Management / SQL Node (Replication Slave)
db006 - Management / SQL Node
db007 - Storage Node
db008 - Storage Node

Everything within each cluster is working fine and creating databases/tables is replicating with no issues between clusters.  If I update tables on either db001 or db005, they replicate between the clusters and I can see the changes on any of the four SQL nodes.

However, if I update a table using db002 or db006, the changes only appear on the other SQL nodes within the cluster - they aren't replicating to the other cluster.  Is there something I'm missing in order to get changes made on either SQL node in either cluster to replicate?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Masters, by definition, do the work.  Slaves, by definition, only do what they're told.

You need [master-master replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html).